# Where Clause On Group Of Columns

Tags: mysql, sql, select, where-clause

I have a data that comes from a retail shop and the columns are below

```
col_1   qty_1   col_2    qty_2    col_3     qty_3
Green   5       Red        8      Yellow     10
```

If I want to know the quantity of Green then I can write a simple query with where col_1 = 'Green'.

But I do not get the color code Green in only col_1. It keeps shuffling between col_1, col_2 and col_3 as shown below

```
col_1   qty_1   col_2    qty_2    col_3     qty_3
Green   5       Red        8      Yellow     10
Yellow  10      Green      7      Red        20
```

How can I have a single query to extract the quantity of Green available without changing the query every time?

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.  Also, what if `green` is in two columns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select case when col_1 = 'Green' then qty_1
            when col_2 = 'Green' then qty_2
            when col_3 = 'Green' then qty_3
       end as qty
from your_table
where 'Green' in (col_1, col_2, col_3)
```

Comment: Sometimes I receive null values for 'Green', how can we handle that?

Comment: How do you want it to be handled if the `qty` column has no value when `col` is *Green*?

Comment: If it is null then the last not null value should be returned

Comment: Or return only the not null rows. I can order by time to extract the latest value

Comment: you better write that into a new question with example data and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue on NULL values you can use COALESCE() condition, if it is NULL then it will be blank:

```
SELECT case when COALESCE(col_1,'') = 'Green' then qty_1
            when COALESCE(col_2,'') = 'Green' then qty_2
            when COALESCE(col_3,'') = 'Green' then qty_3
            end as qty
FROM your_table
WHERE 'Green' IN ( COALESCE(col_1,''), COALESCE(col_2,''), COALESCE(col_3,'') )
;
```

Comment: If I try select * from your_table where 'Green' In(col1,col2,col3) then it doesn't return any value :(